# Proverb/phrase for using a tool/process not intended for its purpose

Tags: phrases, idioms, quotes

I couldn't come up with a better title.  So I have one of my colleague using a wrong tool/process to achieve something that this tool/process is not intended for.  So basically its going to be inefficient and probably a failure.

I am trying to find a quote/proverb/phrase for these kind of situation.

Cheers

Comment: "Don't use a sledgehammer to crack a nut" is perhaps not what you were seeking, but is the metaphor for avoiding an excessive solution to a simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

By *using a wrong tool/process to achieve something that this tool/process is not intended for*, your colleague, in a way, is ***trying to fit a square peg into a round hole***.

TFD(idioms):

> **[square peg in a round hole](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/round+peg+in+a+square+hole)**  (Also, *round peg in a square hole*)
>   *Fig*. someone who is uncomfortable or who does not belong in a particular situation. (**Also the cliché: trying to fit a square peg
>   into a round hole, trying to combine two things that do not belong or
>   fit together.**)
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by
>   The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.

Wiktionary:

> **[square peg in a round hole](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/square_peg_in_a_round_hole)** (*plural* square pegs in round holes)
>
> (idiomatic) **Something** or someone **that does not fit well or at all**;
>   something that will not succeed as attempted, except possibly with
>   much force and effort, or alteration of either the peg or the hole or
>   both beyond recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ELU.  Your reason for looking for this word or phrase is very clear.  As a matter of a fact, it is one of those rare cases where (as far as I can discover) there is no word or phrase for quite a common situation.  But it is such a common situation (type of of behaviour), that I am surprised to find that my searches give me nothing.

> 'to use a sledgehammer to crack a nut'

This is about the use of an excessively elaborate, large or expensive implement or method to solve a very small or minor problem.  That is not quite what you want.  The sledgehammer will work, even though it shatters the nut into an uneatable mess of shell and nut.

I found one word that might do, following the old proverb

> The greeks had a word for it.

There is a word *καταχρησθαι* (catachresthai), which is from the preposition *cata* (κάτα), meaning '*down*', often in a negative sense, an *chresthai* (*χρησθαι*), to use.  I can mean to use up or to misuse.  It did eventually come to have the additional sense of the misuse of **words**.

Does it come into modern English?  That is the problem. It does, but with the very specific meaning of the **misuse of words**.  I find the following entry in Oxford dictionaries:

> The use of a word in an incorrect way, for example the use of mitigate for militate.

Example sentences
Origin
Mid 16th century: from Latin, from Greek katakhrēsis, from katakhrēsthai ‘misuse’, from kata- ‘down’ (expressing the sense ‘wrongly’) + khrēsthai ‘use’.

That is as near as I can get and I fear it is not near enough.  The only way you could get away with coining it would be to become a widely known celebrity and utter it on air or online, so that it catches on, or to make it known within a smaller special group of people in some specialist area (such as engineering).

Otherwise, I see nothing at all wrong with how you yourself expressed the situation!